# Reasons why $AB$ is not full column rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $Rank(A)=m$ and let $B$ be an $n \times k$ matrix with $Rank(B)=k$. Assume $k \leq m$. Under what conditions is $Rank(AB)<k$ and under what conditions is $Rank(AB) = k$?

I originally thought it had to do with $AB_i \neq 0$ but the solutions show that this is not correct.

**edit:** The question is now rewritten for a second time since I don't feel like the solutions answer the question I had in mind.

The original question was "Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $Rank(A)=m$ and let $B$ be an $n \times k$ matrix with $Rank(B)=k$. Assume $k \leq m$. What are the reasons that $Rank(AB)<k$? i.e., why would $Rank(AB) \neq k$?"

After the first edit the question was: "Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $Rank(A)=m$ and let $B$ be an $n \times k$ matrix with $Rank(B)=k$. Assume $k \leq m$. Let $B_1,\ldots,B_{k}$ be the columns of $B$ and assume that $AB_i \neq 0$, for $i=1,\ldots,k$. Is $Rank(AB)=k$?"

Comment: It doesn't have to be $< k$, it has to be $\le k$.  In general, the rank of the product of matrices is at most the minimum of the ranks of those matrices.  Or did you mean $m < k$?

Comment: I should be clearer... I want to know why it would not be exactly equal to $k$. When $A$ is nonsingular then $Rank(AB)=k$. Why doesn't the same logic follow through when $A$ is full row rank?

Answer (score 2):

Try $m=k=2,\; n=3$:
$$A = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr},\
   B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr},\
  AB = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} $$
$A$ and $B$ have rank $2$, and all $A B_i = \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr} \ne 0$, but $AB$ has rank $1$.

Comment: Beat me to it! Except my second row for $A$ was $(0 0 1)$.

Comment: I think to make the result true we need not that $A$ doesn't kill each column of $B$ but that $A$ kills nothing in the column space of $B$.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean "kill nothing in the column space of B"? How does adding a row to A making it nonsingular solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\end{array}\right] 
\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\1\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Your $B$ is in the null space of $A$. I think the only reason that the rank is less than $k$ is precisely when columns of $B$ are in the null space of $A$. Can you find another example where the rank is less than $k$ but columns of $B$ are not in the null space of $A$? It seems like my question is not clear. Let me know what I need to clarify.

Comment: @ancientmathematician. I still don't see how this would be a counterexample. Let $B_1,\ldots,B_k$ be the columns of $B$. I claim that if $AB_i \neq 0$, for $i=1,\ldots,l$ and $AB_i=0$, for $i=l+1,\ldots,k$, then $Rank(AB)=l$.